# Clear previous ajax response data before appending new data

Tags: php, ajax, append

I am trying to **.append()** a selected data from a radio button but it display all the previous respond result.

My HTML :

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT(name) FROM table1";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    $i = 1;
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo '<label>'.$row['name'].'</label>';
        $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE list = '".$row['list']."'";
        $result2 = $conn->query($sql2);
        if ($result2->num_rows > 0) {
            while($row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc()) {
                echo '<input name="group['.$i.']" class="id" type="radio" data-id="'.$row2['id'].'" />'.$row2['list'];
            }
        }
        $sql2 = NULL;
        $i++;
    }
}
$sql = NULL;
```

My ajax to get data and append :

```
$('.id').on('click', function(){
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    $.ajax ({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'url-here',
        data: { id : id },
        success : function(data) {
            $('#list').append(data);
        }
    });
});
```

For PHP side if there is `$_POST['id']` then do mysql query to filter from table and return result.

```
if(isset($_POST['id'])){
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE id = '".$_POST['id']."'";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo '<label>'.$row['name'].'</label>';
        }
    }
}
```

So what happened in my **ajax result box**, it keep appending the previous data that been processed by ajax together with the new data.

**EDIT** : Example append result :

**First result of selected radio button** : `string 1`

**Second result of selected radio button** : `string 2`

So result should be :

1. `string 1`
2. `string 2`

Sorry there was a mistake with my explanation. My ajax box result is resulting something like this :

1. `string 1`
2. `string 2`  **(new data from another selected radio)**
3. `string 2`  **(new data is duplicating)**

If adding select another radio it will become like this :

1. `string 1`
2. `string 2`
3. `string 2`
4. `string 3`  **(new data)**
5. `string 3`  **(new data duplicating)**
6. `string 3`  **(new data duplicating)**
7. `string 3`  **(new data duplicating)**

My ajax box result :

`<div id="list"></div>`

Comment: can u post your php ? just part of this

Comment: @Max check my edited question

Comment: if you add another one and will it become string1 string1 string2 string1 string2 string3?

Comment: @Max Yes you got me right

Comment: yes now because all of your input have the class="id" so jquery will get all of the value then send it to ajax

Comment: Should I use `id` value instead of `class` value?

Comment: if the id will not the same then it will work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153421/discussion-between-max-and-linundus-ondu).

Answer (score 1):

Add any class in label and input

```
  echo '<label class="ajax">'....
  ....
  echo '<input  class="ajax" ...
  ....
```

And Remove in each selection or change in ajax

```
  $('.ajax').remove();
  $('#list').append(data);
```

Or better

```
  $('#list .ajax').remove();
  $('#list').append(data);
```

**Update**

Or simple add `div` to your ajax response

```
$('#list').append("<div class='ajax'>"+data+"</div>");
```

and then use this code

```
 $('#list .ajax').remove();
 $('#list').append(data);
```

Comment: @LinundusOndu :  can you make a simple fiddle for this ?

Comment: It's working and the function is just like `.html` . I don't want to replace with the new data but appending it

Comment: `.html` will replace inner content , you need to to do as I said or make js fiddle similar to your functionality

Answer (score 0):

I think you jQuery looks ok.  It would be possible for your SQL query to have multiple rows as a result.  This could mean that your `id` value is actually returning two rows.  They include the first row and the second row.

Comment: Hello, thank you for the answer but that is not what I'm looking. `.html` will replace the whole result in the `result box` but I wanted to append the result. I want to make it like this https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_html_append_ref

Comment: It sounds from your description like it is doing what you want it to do. If you click on the `.id` it will place a result in the box,  if you click it again it will place the next result next to the last result.  What is not working for you?  Can you describe the problem in a little more detail?

Comment: I have improve my question. Please check it

Comment: Sorry to ask but can you also post the html now?

Comment: Which html that you talking about? The result box?

Comment: You posted the html thank you.  I am curious what you get when you echo this:
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        `echo "This is num of rows: ".$result->num_rows;`
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo '<label>'.$row['name'].'</label>';
        }
    }

Add that echo statement to the last group of code above and if you get more than one row.  Your SQL is returning the multiple rows.

Comment: The result is `This is num of rows: 1`

Comment: Oh sorry, I thought that you are talking about the `php` side. The result is multiple row `This is num of rows: 2`

Comment: I was talking about the PHP side.  If the php is returning two rows,  then then ajax call will return two strings.  It looks like your SQL statement that is processing your ajax request is returning more than one row. What is the value of your `id`?   What is the value of all your `$row2['id']`s?

Comment: For the PHP side is returning only 1 row

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153423/discussion-between-linundus-ondu-and-jeff-mattson).

Answer (score 0):

You should remove a **previously**-attached event handler from the elements to avoid **multiple** click.

```
$('.id').on('click', function(){
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    $.ajax ({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'url-here',
        data: { id : id },
        success : function(data) {
            $('#list').append(data);
            $('.id').off('click'); // remove a previously-attached event handler from the element.
        }
    });
});
```